# How do I check if a ubuntu package is signed or not

Tags: ubuntu, digital-signature

I want to check if a package is signed or not. I do not necessarily want to ensure the validity of the packages - I just want to see if it is signed or not.

Is there a way to do this in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

```
gpg --verify {Package}
```

The above command can be used to check whether an ubuntu package is signed or not.
Actually this does not work for the .deb file itself, only for the metadata files. To see if a .deb file is signed, list its contents with:

```
ar t {Package}
```

and if there is a member called _gpgorigin (as well as debian_binary, control.tar.xz and data.tar.xz) then the package is signed -- though the signature may not be valid or trustworthy.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.